# How to setup Apache 2.2.3 to send "last modified" etc

Tags: apache-2.2, cache, server-setup, last-modified

and to tell browser to reload an object (and/or a page... everything on the site) only if is been modified since last visit time???
htaccess, httpd.conf... have you a ready directive right for my case? Thank You very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[html5boilerplate.com](http://html5boilerplate.com/) includes a [well commented .htaccess file](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/5d693df8baace51754cd60ee2aab451c7cfa20eb/dist/.htaccess) that has many standard settings you should consider. Among them are reasonable settings for expiring the content (Expires, E-tags, ...).

Here's the [documentation on mod_expires](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html).

Answer (score 5):

Note that `Last-Modified` headers are weak cache headers.  The current preference is to use `Cache-Control` headers.

Google has a good article on this.

[Optimize Caching](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching)

> Expires and Cache-Control: max-age. These specify the “freshness
>   lifetime” of a resource, that is, the time period during which the
>   browser can use the cached resource without checking to see if a new
>   version is available from the web server. They are "strong caching
>   headers" that apply unconditionally; that is, once they're set and the
>   resource is downloaded, the browser will not issue any GET requests
>   for the resource until the expiry date or maximum age is reached.
>
> Last-Modified and ETag. These specify some characteristic about the
>   resource that the browser checks to determine if the files are the
>   same. In the Last-Modified header, this is always a date. In the ETag
>   header, this can be any value that uniquely identifies a resource
>   (file versions or content hashes are typical). Last-Modified is a
>   "weak" caching header in that the browser applies a heuristic to
>   determine whether to fetch the item from cache or not. (The heuristics
>   are different among different browsers.) However, these headers allow
>   the browser to efficiently update its cached resources by issuing
>   conditional GET requests when the user explicitly reloads the page.
>   Conditional GETs don't return the full response unless the resource
>   has changed at the server, and thus have lower latency than full GETs.

I recommend using either `Cache-Control` or `Expires` headers as needed since they are strong cache headers.  Some systems will ignore Last-Modified dates.

You can then use a tool like `curl` or http://redbot.org to check the headers.

Comment: FWIW: "weak" is something that Google made up. `Expires` is a totally inappropriate header for resources that do not expire. Some resources may be modified, but not at some expiration date. Google's point is that `Last-Modified` requires a conditional GET, whereas `Expires` allows the browser cache to skip the GET altogether.

Comment: The term *weak* is simply semantics.  The point is that using `Last-Modified` headers in the absence of other caching instructions leaves the cache period up to the HTTP client. If a resource has not been modified since the `Last-Modified` date, the resource should be considered fresh.  In contrast, when using an `Expires` or `Cache-Control` header the origin can set an explicit freshness period.

Comment: "weak" v "strong" is defined at https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-2.1 (Note also to @Dancrumb)